# What encoding is used for the data in account data?

Tags: accounts, encoding

From Slack:

> i saved data to an account as `{foo: 'bar'}`, but it came back as: `{
>   foo: 'YmFy' }`. What encoding is being used, and/or how do you get the
>   plain text/utf8 value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account data is encoded with base64.

Note that the `key` must be a string but `data` can be any kind of binary data (in addition to  a string), so that's why many APIs return it base-64 encoded.

Some examples of decoding this value in various languages:

**Javascript**

```
var decoded = atob('YmFy'); // 'bar'
```

**Go**

```
decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("YmFy")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("decode error:", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(decoded))
```

**PHP**

```
$decoded = base64_decode('YmFy');
```